# Expected E-field results vs simulation results

Tags: electromagnetic

In the below question I wanted to know how they are getting the expect result of .74u for the e field, e field should be v/m it works out correctly for this simple example but as soon as I change the radius of the second sphere to 9 and its charge to +3 and then first sphere to radius 4 and charge -2 when simulating I get effectively 5v/m. ok I get 5v because the fields will add since both vectors will be in the same direction but how do the meters become apart of the units without actually involving the radius? If I perform the math the same as the first example for the second scenario I get way off answers since using the equations for e field and V  E= V/r  which once the radius is more than 1 will not be able to simply add the voltages so really confused as to why my simulations are seemingly just adding the voltages for the max electric field. Can someone point out the disconnect please.

[image]

Comment: They are talking about a potential difference (U in Volts) whereas you mention charges (Q, mostly in Coulomb) without mentioning the units on your spheres. Further, in the original problem, distances are given in a constant ratio to radius, but you give absolute numbers for different radii. Your question as such can not be comprehended I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok I can see that. It throws me off a little because the simulation software seems to essentially use the U method but displays the field maximum values with units volts per meter. which it still would be just over 1 okay I got it  Thank you

Comment: There still is a disconnect in the sense that 'they' speak of a potential difference withouth giving any charge or capacity, and you apply a charge and then seem to expect some kind of result that can be compared with what is given in the original problem. 
It could also be helpful if you would give the [1] which they refer to.

Comment: [1] was not an equation just example[1] .I may have been seeking math over my head but the simulation only took a radius of the spheres and a potential of 3v and -2v. once it ran it had charge values in coulombs for those spheres, I wanted to replicate the scenario mathematically and failed to figure out how to do that.

Comment: May I ask what was the 'C' that you have been working with? In the example it is defined as $$C=R_0/0.2$$ but with your new dimensions there are two different radii.